# Wide column text in two column latex document

Tags: two-column

I am new to latex and writing paper for a journal where the text is created in two column mode. For figures and tables, I can use the `{figure*}` and `{table*}` environment and this inserts the figures and tables in the wide mode spanning the width of the document.

How can one do the same for a paragraph of text without inserting a new page in the document?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you could place the text in one of the floating environments, and just not insert a caption.  but it's likely that the journal editors don't want that, so maybe you had better ask there whether it's permitted

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will give it a try. The reason I ask is that they have a special acknowledgement section and for some reason it seems to overlap the text with the other column. But I will ask them on how I can fix it as it messes up the readability.

Comment: Try to find cause whay your text is wider than column. In normal circumstances  a plain text without extremely long words is newer wider than column width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (in the `shipunov` bundle):

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{cuted}

    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{strip}
    \lipsum[3-4]
    \end{strip}
    \lipsum[5-8]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked very well!